# A correlation analysis must or should be made before a regression?

Tags: regression, correlation

I want to make a regression analysis. A correlation analysis must or should be made before a regression?.

Comment: Have you read the thread on [what diagnostics to do with regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32600)?

Comment: What will the correlation analysis consist of and what will it tell you that the regression won't?