# Which criterion should be used for transformations of dependent variables?

Tags: data-transformation

When transforming the dependent variables, I know R^2 and related criterion is not suitable for model selection. Then which one should I use?

Comment: the question is not clear...  model selection for what?

Comment: In a simple linear regression, I want to select the best lambda when doing box-cox transformation for the dependent variable . Thank you.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242526/multiple-linear-regression-residual-normality-and-transformations  or the [list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform+depen*+variab*+answers%3A1+box-cox). Probably a dup in there

Comment: This question is so general that it deserves a general answer, which is provided by the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are exclusively interested in prediction (and not at all in explanation) then I think you should only transform variables for substantive reasons, not statistical ones.

EDIT 2 For instance, it often makes sense to take logs of money variables such as income or price.

EDIT 1 Note that not all statisticians share my views.

If the assumptions of OLS regression are not met, then, rather than transform, you can use a different model, such as quantile regression or robust regression.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I have to do some transformation for the response and compare them, which the requirement of my hw.

Comment: It is worth noting that your opinion very well may be a minority one among statisticians, especially those exposed to Tukey's work on EDA.  Tukey advocated using exploratory analysis to uncover effective ways of re-expressing data.  This was one of the cornerstones of his approach to all data analysis.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.  But Tukey didn't have the tools that we have - at least, not in any practical way. I know quantile regression is very old in theory, but it only became practical with computer.

Comment: There are many situations e.g fitting power functions or exponentials where taking logs first is natural and convenient and often the best thing to do. I don't know whether you call that circumstance substantive or statistical. The same applies, although on the whole with less force, to several other transformations.

Comment: @NickCox   If it's "natural" then I think that implies substantive. E.g. taking logs of income or price variables. If your theory suggests some other relationship, that's substantive too.

Comment: @Eva If this is HW then you need to add the self-study tag and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: With many kinds of data being willing to use logarithmic scale arises from past experience that it is a good idea. Some people call that theory.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions above. I am sorry for not asking a good questions here. And actually, I need a statistical criterion(some numeric methods like R^2, MSE and so on) to measure how to select a lambda among 0 and 1 when conducting power transformation for the response. (y^\lambda, and the response y is salary.). I learned before that R^2 does not work in such a situation. And MSE also not suitable because the scale is different for different \lambda. So I am confused which one I can use in such a situation. Thank you for help!