# Check multi variate regression conditions in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, forecasting

I am new to statistics and running a multi variate regression model in R to predict number of days. How do I check if my data is best fit for multi linear regression technique. Do I need to check the distribution of my response(y) variable or explanatory(x's) variables and see if they are normally distributed?
If yes, then how would i do that in R? and if no, then what i need to see if the data is fit for the multi linear regression in R?

Many thanks in advance!
P.K.

Comment: For such a broad question you might need to have a look at a Statistics and data analysis book.

Comment: Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20diagnostic.  Perhaps the most directly applicable thread is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32600.  **NB** It sounds like you have a *multiple regression* model rather than a "multivariate" model.  The latter would be predicting a vector value, whereas "number of days" is a scalar.